# Replace the column values of a dictionary with value of another another dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

1.**Input**: I have 2 dataframes

```
ID PS
1  a
2  c
3  d
```

another dataframe:

```
emp PS
pp  a
qq  b
rr  c
```

2.**Expected Result:** I want to replace the value of df2 in df1 if the PS is same.

```
ID PS
1  pp
2  rr
3  d
```

**Code** I tried:

```
df1= df1.to_dict()
df2= df2.to_dict()

df1.replace({"PS": df2.values()})
df1
```

But the replacing is not happening.

Comment: Can you post the results of `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(df2.merge(df1, how='right', on=['PS'])
    .fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)[['ID', 'emp']]
    .rename(columns={'emp': 'PS'}))
```

Output:

```
  ID  PS
0  1  pp
1  2  rr
2  3   d
```

Comment: It is fast processing like I needed but for a dataframe with 1000 rows it is generating double more than 2000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df1['PS'] = df1.PS.replace(dict(df2.iloc[:, ::-1].values))
```

OUTPUT:

```
   ID  PS
0   1  pp
1   2  rr
2   3   d
```

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks a lot.
But it's processing time is far too long

Comment: Is there any alternative or work around to this, then it would be a great help.